# How do I test that the code is actually starting a go routine?

Tags: unit-testing, go

if I am creating a go routine in my code, how do I write a test case that tests whether a goroutine is being created.

Comment: Why would you think it's not being started?

Comment: If `go somefunction()` happens, the goroutine is created. This is covered by the Go language/runtime tests, not something you need to test in your own applications. This is like testing that `1 + 1` results in `2`.

Answer (score 6):

> how do I write a test case that tests whether a goroutine is being created

This is never what you're looking for. Instead you should instrument your test to check that whatever the go routine is supposed to do actually happens.